# Comparing enumType values with int

Tags: c#, enums

I'm developing a C# application and I have the following enum:

```
public enum TourismItemType : int
{
     Destination = 1,
     PointOfInterest = 2,
     Content = 3
}
```

And I also have a int variable, and I want to check that variable to know it is equal to `TourismItemType.Destination`, like this:

```
int tourismType;
if (int.TryParse(NavigationContext.QueryString.Values.First(), out tourismType))
{
    switch (tourismType)
    {
        case TourismItemType.Destination:
            ShowDestinationInfo();
            break;
        case TourismItemType.PointOfInterest:
            ShowPointOfInterestInfo();
            break;
    }
}
```

But it throws an error.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I know you have answers now but in general put in teh details of the error that is thrown rather than just saying there was one. Even if the error means nothing to you it might mean somethign to somebody else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast `tourismType` to your enum type as there is no implicit conversion from ints.

```
switch ((TourismItemType)tourismType)
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running .NET 4 then you can use the [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse.aspx) method:

```
TourismItemType tourismType;
if (Enum.TryParse(NavigationContext.QueryString.Values.First(), out tourismType))
{
    switch (tourismType)
    {
        case TourismItemType.Destination:
            ShowDestinationInfo();
            break;
        case TourismItemType.PointOfInterest:
            ShowPointOfInterestInfo();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse tourismType to your enum type using [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) or you can treat enum values as int like: `case (int)TourismType.Destination.`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int tourismType;
if (int.TryParse(NavigationContext.QueryString.Values.First(), out tourismType))
{
    switch (tourismType)
    {
        case (int)TourismItemType.Destination:
            ShowDestinationInfo();
            break;
        case (int)TourismItemType.PointOfInterest:
            ShowPointOfInterestInfo();
            break;
    }
}
```

or

```
int tourismType;
TourismItemType tourismTypeEnum;
if (int.TryParse(NavigationContext.QueryString.Values.First(), out tourismType))
{
    tourismTypeEnum = (TourismItemType)tourismType;
    switch (tourismTypeEnum)
    {
        case TourismItemType.Destination:
            ShowDestinationInfo();
            break;
        case TourismItemType.PointOfInterest:
            ShowPointOfInterestInfo();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
int tourismType;
if ( int.TryParse(NavigationContext.QueryString.Values.First(), out tourismType )
{
    if ( Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TourismItemType), tourismType) )
    {
        switch ((TourismItemType)tourismType)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // tourismType not a valid TourismItemType
    }
}
else
{
    // NavigationContext.QueryString.Values.First() not a valid int
}
```

Of course you could also handle invalid tourismType in the switch's `default:` case.